# `ngx-translate` - after deply getting error as `/assets/i18n/shared/fr.json: 404 OK"`

Tags: angular7, ngx-translate

I am using `ngx-translate` with my angular 7 app. it works fine with local. when i deploy in to server i am getting an error as :

```
message: "Http failure response for https://iang.azurewebsites.net/assets/i18n/shared/fr.json: 404 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://iang.azurewebsites.net/assets/i18n/shared/fr.json"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

in my local build i see there is a `assets` folder with rquired `json` files are available. I am using `microsoft` azure for deployment. how to fix this?
already i have set prefix to `app` in my angular.json file. what else need to do?

any one help me?

Comment: Did you get any solution?